# Как в MongoDB пройтись по всей коллекции и удалить последний элемент у вложенного массива каждого документа?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

читаю документацию по MongoDB, там есть оператор [$pop](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/) который делает то, что мне надо.
Я пробую сделать это через mongoose.

Схема:

```
const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    country: {type: String},
    code: {type: String},
    region: [{
        name: {type: String},
        path: {type: Array},
        city: [{
            name: {type: String},
            path: {type: Array},
            latitude: {type: String},
            longitude: {type: String},
        }],
    }],
})
```

Запрос: Удалять мне надо у массива region.path последнее значение.

```
const savedDoc = await Geo.updateMany(
    {},
    { $pop: { region: { path: 1 } } },
    { multi: true },
  )
```

И получаю ошибку:

```
MongoError: Expected a number in: region: { path: 1 }
```

Помогите составить правильный запрос.

Update:
Попробовал так

```
{ region: { $pop: { path: 1 } } },
```

Очистило весь массив region

Comment: а во всех документах в поле path есть данные?

Comment: @Дмытрык Нет, у некоторых пустой массив region, соответственно там нет и path

Comment: попробуйте дописать в условиях поиска проверку на наличие этого поля. Для этого используется оператор `$exists` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такой запрос:

```
const savedDoc = await Geo.updateMany(
    { "region.path": {$exists: true}},
    { $pop: { 'region.$.path': 1 } },
    { multi: true },
  )
```

Comment: Получаю ту же ошибку.